# Встроенное видео в слайдере

Tags: javascript

Всем Привет!

Есть простой слайдер на javascript, из картинок и видео встроенное через iframe. 
Задача - сделать чтобы при воспроизведении видео, слайдер останавливался, и при нажатии на паузу продолжал свою работу.

Я только начал изучать этот язык,  вот и столкнулся с первыми трудностями ))

Буду благодарен за помощь!!

http://jsfiddle.net/euTXh/

Сам код:

```
var secDuration = 4;
var image = 1;    
var maxImages = 5;    
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');    
var timeout

function changeImage(requiredImage) {     
  if (!requiredImage && requiredImage != 0){     
    if(image < maxImages){        
      image++;        
    }        
    else{        
      image = 1;        
    }    
  }    
  else{     
    if(requiredImage > maxImages){        
      image = 1;        
    }        
    else if(requiredImage < 1){         
      image = maxImages;        
    }
    else{
      image = requiredImage; 
    }    
  }

  slider.className = "image"+image;      
  clearTimeout(timeout)    
  timeout = setTimeout("changeImage()",secDuration*800);    
}

function nextImage(){    
  changeImage(image+1);    
}

function prevImage(){    
  changeImage(image-1);    
}

changeImage(1);
```

Comment: if (!requiredImage && requiredImage != 0) интересненько

Comment: выложите пример на jsfiddle

Comment: вот, только слайдер здесь вообще не работает почему то

http://jsfiddle.net/euTXh/